# How to bulk rename files and remove additional characters after extension in linux

Tags: bash, video, terminal, rename

I have too many files urls in a txt file that i've downloaded using this bash command

```
awk '{url=$1; $1="";{sub(/ /,"");out=url" -O \""$0"\""}; print out}' file.txt | xargs -L 1 wget
```

this bash command above is supposed to get each file url and name and then rename them while downloading with the original name that is listed in front of each file url , the txt file containing those urls and their respective names is organized as follows:

```
http://example.com/1425233/47188.mp4 Abaixo de Zero (2021).mp4
http://example.com/1425233/47185.mp4 A Sentinela (2021).mp4
http://example.com/1425233/46849.mp4 Eu Me Importo (2021).mp4
http://example.com/1425233/47933.mp4 Loucura de Amor (2021).mp4
```

Well done, until this point everything is working correctly, the problem now is that when the download finishes, when i put the ls command in the terminal each file is presented with the title looking like this, all of them are looking like this:

```
'Abaixo de Zero (2021).mp4'$'\r'
'A Sentinela (2021).mp4'$'\r'
'Eu Me Importo (2021).mp4'$'\r'
'Loucura de Amor (2021).mp4'$'\r'
```

so this problem is causing the video not to play anymore, but when i rename manually to mp4 again then the '$'\r' string disappears and the video is able to play...

So having said that i want a linux command that can bulk rename all of the files  and remove this '$'\r' string...

And then when listing in terminal the  files would only be:

```
'Abaixo de Zero (2021).mp4'
'A Sentinela (2021).mp4'
'Eu Me Importo (2021).mp4'
'Loucura de Amor (2021).mp4'
```

thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rename the existing files, please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *mp4$'\r'; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f%$'\r'}"
done
```

It assumes the *mp4 files are located in the same directory. If you want to fix the filenames in the current directory recursively, please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*mp4$'\r'; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f%$'\r'}"
done
```

BTW if you want to fix the filenames downloading from now on, modify your `awk` command as:

```
awk '{url=$1; $1="";{sub(/ /,""); sub(/\r$/, "");out=url" -O \""$0"\""}; print out}' file.txt | xargs -L 1 wget
```

It removes the trailing CR characters out of the names in `file.txt` then passes the corrected filenames to `wget`.

Comment: Many thanks tshiono, your reply really exceeded expectations, by improving the awk command that i use to download the files...you really saved me, now the files are being renamed correctly while downloading ...thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback with heartfelt message! It encourages me a lot. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

you can take an advantage of bash string manipulation and do a move of the original file to a file sub-string like so:

```
$ touch normal_file_extra
$ fileVar=normal_file_extra
$ echo ${fileVar::-6}
normal_file
$ mv $fileVar ${fileVar::-6}
# previous command substract 6 chars from the original file
$ ls
normal_file
```